# How to find the oldest and most recent date value in mysql in one query itself

Tags: mysql

I had a question about an exercise im trying where it asks me to find the manufacturing date of the oldest item as well as the most recent item in a table here
[image]

if anyone could help me i would appreciate it thx a ton

Comment: Please provide code of what you already tried

Comment: @AdityaPandey, please consider accepting one of the answers if any has answered your question adequately.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the dates the query you need is:

```
SELECT MIN(MDATE) AS oldestDate, MAX(MDATE) AS newestDate FROM Product;
```

If you want the entire rows one option is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Product
WHERE MDATE IN (
    (SELECT MIN(MDATE) FROM Product),
    (SELECT MAX(MDATE) FROM Product)
)
```

Comment: genus answer :)